# How to remove PDF document from Foxit Reader Cloud?

Tags: security, pdf, privacy, cloud, foxit-reader

I used the latest version of Foxit Reader to open a .pdf file. There was a pop-up message. When I clicked "I know", the .pdf file was immediately uploaded to the Internet.

I was not signed in to any Foxit account.

Then there was a whole array of sharing buttons and options.

This is a confidential document. I do NOT want it publicly available on the Internet. Currently it is made publicly available by Foxit.

How do I remove this document?

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question. But why do you think that it is **publicly available**? If I'm not mistaken these documents are in no way shared publicly without you directly sharing the link.

Comment: Thanks @Yisroel Tech, the link is a **super short link**, much like how Microsoft OneDrive used to give out before realizing the security danger of brute force search to expose thousands of private files. This is an important privacy problem that needs to be addressed. I'm wondering why my question has been downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same thing happen. I contacted Foxit at the phone number on this page:

www.connectedpdf.com/contact.html

USA support: 1-866-693-6984

They answered the phone immediately. Once I explained the problem, they had to go talk to someone with more admin rights. It took them about a week to take the file down.

Comment: I also contacted Foxit Support. They were able to remove this .pdf file for me. Initially I had to explain to them that I was not signed in when the file unintentionally uploaded. Therefore technically there is no owner for the file. So a Foxit Administrator had to remove it manually. I'm sure it would save them much hassle if they only allowed uploading when a user signs in to their Foxit account. This way it would be the user's prerogative to remove the document as they wish.